# Why does Satellite need a kickstartable distribution for cloned channels, but not on the official main Red Hat Channel?

Tags: redhat, rhel5, kickstart, provisioning, satellite

I have been using Satellite for a while now and I am able to kickstart machines directly from the official main RH channels

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64) 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)
```

I want to create a frozen Red Hat Linux 5.7-channel and kickstart new servers from this channel. I have done this with the command spacewalk-clone-by-date on 2012-02-01 (latest version was RHEL 5.7).

It seems however that now I need to add a distribution under kickstart->distributions in order to use the new cloned channels for kickstarting.

How come a distribution under kickstart->distributions is needed for custom (cloned) channels, but not for the official Red Hat channels?

Answer (score 0):

The Satellite already has the bits required to kickstart the main channels - it comes with the channel, it just doesn't get cloned to your clone channel.